# Replace Or Remove Dote (.) from keys string in json string for inserting in mongodb

Tags: c#, json, regex, mongodb, bson

I Want to insert Json into mongoDB with C# Driver , nut i get exception becuse you can't insert json with keys that contain Dot (.) 
now i want to replace all Dots in Keys with _ or something else ...

I try this: `((?<=(\w))(\.)(?=(\w+)))`

it select all Dots between string but the problem is cannot verify the keys For example if i have website name in Json values also select Dots in website name ... 
now i need a way to find all Dots in Between Words that End with( ":  )
its a sample of json :

```
"activity:12356", "permalink": "https://www.hostname.com/fff/update    /urn:li:activity:123465", "tracking": {"trackingId": "sdjahgs/sfkdjk=="}, "value": {"com.site.aaaa.bbb.ccc": {"actor": {"com.aaa.sss.ddd.wwww": {"urn": ....
```

here i want to replace "com.aaa.sss.ddd.wwww" with "com_aaa_sss_ddd_wwww" but my regex select dots in www.hostname.com

i also try something like `((?<=(\w))(\.)(?=(\w+)))(":$)` but not work

Answer (score 0):

It is quite hard to achieve it with regex only, but simple regex combined with extra code to replace dots will give you desired reult:

```
var s = @"""activity:12356"", ""permalink"": ""https://www.hostname.com/fff/update    /urn:li:activity:123465"", ""tracking"": {""trackingId"": ""sdjahgs/sfkdjk==""}, ""value"": {""com.site.aaaa.bbb.ccc"": {""actor"": {""com.aaa.sss.ddd.wwww"": {""urn"": ....";
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"""[^""]+"":");
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
  var replace = match.Value.Replace('.', '_');
  s = s.Replace(match.Value, replace);
}
```

Pattern used: `"[^"]+":`, which means:

match `"`, then match one or more characted other than `"` with `[^"]+`, and at the end match `":` literally.